# CMAKE - Glob files in post build

Tags: cmake, copy, glob

I want to copy intermediate object files from build folder into another folder.
I have used : `file(GLOB OUTPUT_COMPILED_FILES_POST CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "IntCode/*/*" "ApplicationComps/*/src/Common/*.*)"`
to collect the names of the files as they are plenty.

and then I used `file(COPY ${OUTPUT_COMPILED_FILES_POST} DESTINATION ${OBJECTS_FOLDER})` to copy the files but It doesn't do anything as when the glob command is working the files are not yet generated.

I have multiple sub directories the 4th one has add_executable which generates object files and exe file the fifth and sixth sub directories need some object files.

So. My question:

**Is there any other way to do this?**

Comment: What are your purposes for doing this? If you are using them to build another target, have you tried making them an OBJECT library?

Comment: I agree with Dorito Johnson; thus seems very ill-conceived. [What are you actually trying to do?](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Usually this kind of task is best done using `install` commands. In addition to using a object library you may want to an install command for this target and set specify the install prefix path at the time of configuration.

Comment: I am trying to copy the objects files from the build folder once the add_executable finish generating the exe file.
I have multiple sub directories the 4th one has add_executable which generates object files and exe file 
the fifth and sixth sub directories need some object files.

Comment: "I have multiple sub directories the 4th one has add_executable which generates object files and exe file the fifth and sixth sub directories need some object files." add this detail to your question.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why people are changing the question you're asking, but I have attempted to answer your original question rather than insert my own interpretation about what you're "really trying to achieve". If you really mean to ask the same question as others have interpreted it as, perhaps you should consider closing this question as a duplicate of another (this is of course assuming there is a duplicate answer on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 1):

If you can refactor your glob and instead only copy the files under a certain directory, you can use this command

```
add_custom_command(TARGET bar
    # Run after all other rules within the target have been executed
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory source destination
    COMMENT "This command will be executed after building bar"
)
```

Comment: Do not glob without CONFIGURE_DEPENDS, but better yet, don't glob.

Comment: `message` without the `STATUS` argument prints to stderr, which can break certain CI systems

Comment: @AlexReinking It sounds like you want me to remove those from the answer I gave; is that correct? I have edited my answer.

Comment: I downvoted the answer for the provided reasons and I have upvoted the answer since it has been improved.

Answer (score 0):

> I have multiple sub directories the 4th one has add_executable which generates object files and exe file the fifth and sixth sub directories need some object files.

You can achieve this with object libraries in CMake. See below for a sketch and the documentation here:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#linking-object-libraries
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries

Suppose you have a higher-level CMakeLists.txt file with:

```
...
add_subdirectory(subdir1)
add_subdirectory(subdir2)
add_subdirectory(subdir3)
add_subdirectory(subdir4)
add_subdirectory(subdir5)
add_subdirectory(subdir6)
...
```

Then in subdir4's CMakeLists.txt you would write:

```
add_library(target4objs OBJECT src1.cpp src2.cpp ...)
add_executable(target4 extra_src_not_shared.cpp ...)
target_link_libraries(target4 PRIVATE target4objs)
```

And in subdir5/6 you would write:

```
add_executable(target5 src1.cpp ...)
target_link_libraries(target5 PRIVATE target4objs)
```

General advice: manually copying files from the build tree to either elsewhere in the build tree or especially to the source tree is practically never needed and a bad idea.

Comment: I have a practical example; I want to copy GLSL shader source files to the build output because I run my debug executable from the debug directory. When the executable runs, it looks for shader sources and compiles and links them when it's running. The original question is something I am curious how you would support with those random links you showed. There's no resource folder in those links.

Comment: @activedecay - it sounds like you want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69890019/823282

Comment: It sounds like you think we should [vote to close this question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: @activedecay - no, I don't think we should close this question. As I see it, your comment had little to do with either my answer or this question.