# What cmake command will copy a directory of files to a directory in a post build step

Tags: cmake

I have a set of resource files that have *nothing to do* with the build steps of GCC or some other compiler's output. I need them copied from a folder in my project to the cmake build output folder. The goal is for the executable, when run from the build output folder, can see the resources.

How do people typically copy and install resources in cmake builds? Additionally, I want them copied regardless of changes in the build and I want it executed every time I run some cmake command, like build. See below for what I tried to solve this issue.

#### For example:

I have a bunch of shader files that I want copied. All shaders/* files should be copied into a directory in the build output called "shaders", because that's where the executable for the program lives.

```
file(GLOB out shaders/*)
foreach (o ${out})
    message("${o} was copied to shaders")
    file(COPY ${o} DESTINATION shaders)
endforeach ()
```

This only works sometimes, like when I reload the CMake project, e.g.:

```
/opt/clion-2021.2.3/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_DEPENDS_USE_COMPILER=FALSE \
  -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" \
  /home/hack/glad
```

Also, it doesn't execute "POST_BUILD", so the lastest version of the `shaders/a.vert` file doesn't get copied to the shaders/ directory in the output.

I tried using this, too, but it gave me some headaches:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET my-executable POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy shaders/* shaders)
```

I think there's something incorrect with that above, because it wasn't run every POST_BUILD if the build's code didn't change. I don't care if the build's code doesn't change because the files in shaders/* could have changed and should be copied regardless of cmake determining if there was a change in my-executable.

Comment: *"I don't care if the build's code doesn't change because the files in shaders/* could have changed"* Are the sharder files generated during the build process? It doesn't sound like you added the custom command to the correct target in this case. Are those just files that are edited entirely independent of the CMake project? If that is the case `add_custom_target(... ALL ...)` may be what you're looking, since this allows you to add a target that's always built during the build of the default target (`all`).

Answer (score 0):

This gist on github was very helpful, [here](https://gist.github.com/baiwfg2/39881ba703e9c74e95366ed422641609) but the gist that applies to my question is included below.

```
add_custom_target(bar
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/shaders
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/shaders
        COMMENT "copying ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders to ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/shaders"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        )
```

The above code creates a `bar` cmake target that can be run separately with Make bar; then, if you add another target that requires those resources (the shaders above are resources for this other executable) then you can tie the dependency together using `add_dependencies` like this:

```
add_executable(a
        main.c
        opengl.c)
add_dependencies(a bar)
```

Now, every time the `a` target is run, the `bar` target is run as well, which has the effect of creating the directory and copying the files.

This was good enough for me, but to finish up, you can use this to create the files in a post build step after the other dependency is finished running:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET bar
    # Run after all other rules within the target have been executed
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND echo "executing a POST_BUILD command"
    COMMENT "This command will be executed after building bar"
    VERBATIM
)
```

Note that `${CMAKE_COMMAND}` in the above examples of `add_custom_command` is a variable that points to the cmake executable, and you can run `cmake -E` to see the very helpful list of commands that come with cmake.

*YIKES* the post build step is only running after bar's target is built, not `a`'s target. Hopefully, somebody can help me answer this better. I would still like to know how to copy files after a target is built, unless that's completely unnecessary and nobody should ever want to do that.